# jQuery Chosen Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

So I'm using a jQuery plugin called Chosen for my dropdowns and I notice that the values that I have in the options is not on the chosen lists

Here's the Default:

```
<select id="coating">
    <option value="0">Varnish</option>
    <option value="50">Gloss</option>
    <option value="34">Matte</option>
    <option value="0">Overlaminate</option>
    <option value="10">Clear Gloss</option>
    <option value="11">Clear Matte</option>
</select>
```

And here's what Chosen resulted with:

```
<ul class="chosen-results">
    <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="0">Varnish</li>
    <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">Gloss</li>
    <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2">Matte</li>
    <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3">Overlaminate</li>
    <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4">Clear Gloss</li>
    <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="5">Clear Matte</li>
</ul>
```

So I'm wondering if there's a way to get the values from the option carry over to the chosen lists.

Comment: just curious if you give it something other than a number say a_50, a_34 will they then carry over ?

Comment: can you link to the plugin and show the code the initializes the dropdown

Comment: @BillPull [link](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and using `$("select").chosen();` is all I did.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/o9bbpgbh/ look at this. Can you explain more?

Comment: that's interesting @RejithRKrishnan click the drop down and inspect the element. makes me wonder where it is pulling the value from

Comment: The plugin changes the value of connected `<select>`. The plugin must be saving the options to an array or some other data structure. I did not analyze the code and `data-option-array-index` attribute has the value of the index which points to each options of initial `<select>`

Comment: it looks like they are leaving the select in tact and then then creating a ul li structure to represent the select the question the OP really needs to answer is what is the ultimate goal

Comment: My goal is not to get the selected values. My goal is when the value="0" I'll be able to let's say bold the text since they're just categories. But like you said it created a new structure and the li elements doesn't have any value attribute. I hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED to include** `optgroup`

With this...

```
<select id="coating">
    <optgroup label="Varnish">
        <option value="50">Gloss</option>
        <option value="34">Matte</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Overlaminate">
        <option value="10">Clear Gloss</option>
        <option value="11">Clear Matte</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

You can do this:

```
$("#coating").change(function() {
    var v = $(this).val();
    alert(v);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jreljac/a38vLuoh/1/

You should get the value you are expecting.  This plugin uses the hidden select element to send all the data.  If you are submitting in a traditional form make sure to include a `name` attribute.

The `optgroup` tag groups the items in a select for you - they are not selectable and items in that tag are nested under them http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp

Comment: But my goal is not to get the value of selected option. The reason that there's value of "0" is because they're categories, so I'll be able to let's say bold the text. But since Chosen created a new structure of elements and if you inspect those elements it doesn't have the value attribute. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @OpuLance I think you are looking for `optgroup`.  See my edit.

Comment: I did not know about this `optgroup`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @OpuLance Good. If you feel it's a complete answer take a second and click the accept answer checkmark. It's a good way for both you and I to gain reputation on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can get the values you select.

```js
$("#coating")
  .chosen()
  .change(function() {
    alert($(this).val())
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<select id="coating">
  <option value="0">Varnish</option>
  <option value="50">Gloss</option>
  <option value="34">Matte</option>
  <option value="0">Overlaminate</option>
  <option value="10">Clear Gloss</option>
  <option value="11">Clear Matte</option>
</select>
```